# How do you move a class to the back of the line?

Tags: jquery, css

I have table cells with `class="a"`, and/or `class="b": class="a b"`.

css:

```
.a {
background-color:blue;
}
.b {
background-color:green;
}
```

Where the two intersect, the color is green.  I'd like to make it so that when the user hovers over a table cell, then all the cells that contain that class turn to that color.
So far, I have:

```
$('td.a').add('td.b').hover(function() {
    var myClassName = this.className;
    $('td.' + myClassName).each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass(myClassName);
    });
});
```

This works only once because removeClass() is destructive.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Manipulating the order of class names on an object shouldn't change anything.  The order of CSS rules can matter, but not the order of classes.

Comment: So, the color should actually be blue? I don't quite understand...

Comment: Oh right!  I got mixed up. The order of the classes doesn't matter - it's the order that the css is applied!

Answer (score 3):

I could be misunderstanding your question, and if I am, I apologise.

---

To style something on hover if it has *either* class `a` or class `b`, use this selector:

```
.a:hover, .b:hover {
    /* Hover state */
}
```

---

To style something on hover if it has *both* class `a` *and* class `b`, use this selector:

```
.a.b:hover {
    /* Hover state */
}
```

Can you explain your question a little better please?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Use another class as a placeholder.

```
$('.a').hover(function() {
    $('.a.b').addClass('b-holder').removeClass('b');
}, function() {
    $('.a.b-holder').addClass('b').removeClass('b-holder');
});
```

`.a.b` references any elements that contain both classes.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/ZhRvG/

---

### Solution 2

Add a third class in your stylesheet.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/Lg3aG/2/

CSS...

```
.a {
    background-color:blue;
}
.b {
    background-color:green;
}
.ab {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

jQuery...

```
$('.a').hover(function() {
    $('.a.b').toggleClass('ab');
});
```

---

### Solution 3

Add inline styles, which will override your stylesheet.

```
$('.a').hover(function() {
    $('.a.b').css('background-color', 'blue');
}, function() {
    $('.a.b').css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/Jj4SB/